# Assertion function that returns a value?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a function like this:

```
function assert<T>(condition: T, msg?: string): T & asserts condition {
  if (!condition) {
    throw new Error(msg)
  }
  return condition
}
```

The goal is to return `condition` unmodified, preserving its type, but also informing the compiler that the returned value is truthy. This would allow it to be used as a standalone statement, but also unobtrusively inside an expression:

```
const success: bool = true
// ... some code that might set success = false
assert(success)

const element: HTMLElement = assert(document.getElementById('foo'))
```

Unfortunately, the above syntax does not work ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwM6oKYCcoB4AqAfABQQIAmMsCAXIvgDSIC2qA5gPx2pRYxhsAlHXyIAZCnTYoqRGTCVqSAN4BYAFCJEMYImIBCeYvhhBiNZq2IoACyxwA7ojAYnAUSz2sxVkI1aAX39ELAwoECwkIyoTDSD1IA)). Is there a way to express this in TypeScript?

I can't find any official documentation on assertion functions except the [Release notes for TypeScript 3.7](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions), and those only demonstrate assertion functions that implicitly return `void`.

The best I can come up with is a workaround for object types only, because those can never be falsy:

```
function assert<T extends object>(condition: T | null | undefined, msg?: string): T {
  if (!condition) {
    throw new Error(msg)
  }
  return condition
}
```

Comment: Mayhap you could use the comma operator! i.e. `(assert(ok), ok)`. Pair it with a temporary variable & it can come kinda close: https://tsplay.dev/WKbZGm

Comment: @jason Interesting idea! But if it's going to take two lines, I think `const v = document.getElementById('foo'); assert(v);` is much easier to understand at a glance.

Answer (score 13):

#### Q: Assertion function that returns a value?

#### A: Not possible

It's hard to find because it's not explicitly in the docs, but we do have authoritative sources explicitly stating that assertion function implicitly return `void`, so the answer is no, assertion functions cannot return a value.

##### Authoritative sources

###### [Typescript Github: PR #32695 Assertions in control flow analysis](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/32695)

> An asserts return type predicate implies that the returned value is of type void, and there is no provision for returning values of other types.

[image] [Anders Hejlsberg](https://github.com/ahejlsberg)

*(this is straight from the horse's mouth; Anders Hejlsberg wrote the code so he knows!)*

###### [Typescript issue tracker: #34636 ReturnType support for assertions](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34636)

> This is by design, according to the PR introducing this features:
>
> > A function call is analyzed as an assertion call or never-returning call when
> >
> > 1. the call occurs as a top-level expression statement, and
> > 2. the call specifies a single identifier or a dotted sequence of identifiers for the function name, and
> > 3. each identifier in the function name references an entity with an explicit type, and
> > 4. the function name resolves to a function type with an asserts return type or an explicit never return type annotation.
>
> The first item states that the call must occur as a top-level statement, this means that the call can't be nested in an expression (such as a parameter to another function or in an assignment). This means that effectively, even if you could return from an assertion function, using it in a position where the return value could be use, the function would not be analyzed as an assertion but rather as a regular function call. So it is best to implicitly just say that an assertion function returns void. This is also outlined in the PR:
>
> > An asserts return type predicate implies that the returned value is of type void, and there is no provision for returning values of other types.

[image] [Titian Cernicova-Dragomir](https://github.com/dragomirtitian)

*(Titian is a `contributor` on the Typescript project)*

##### Community sources

Some examples of community sources stating that return types can not be specified for assertion functions.

###### [dev.to - Typescript Type Assertions](https://dev.to/smeijer/typescript-type-assertions-4klf))

> Where type guards must return a boolean, assertion functions must return void

[image] [Stephan Meijer](https://dev.to/smeijer)

###### [2ality.com - TypeScript: narrowing types via type guards and assertion functions - 5.2.2](https://2ality.com/2020/06/type-guards-assertion-functions-typescript.html#assertion-signature%3A-asserts-%C2%ABarg%C2%BB-is-%C2%ABtype%C2%BB)

> **5.2.2: Assertion signature: asserts «arg» is «type»**
>
> ```
> function assertIsString(value: unknown): asserts value is string {
>   if (typeof value !== 'string') {
>     throw new Error(); // assertion error
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> **Assertion signature**: asserts value is string
>
> **Result**: void, exception

[image] [Axel Rauschmayer](http://dr-axel.de/)

##### Official docs

*Sadly, I could not find an authorative answer in the docs...*

###### [Handbook: Narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html)

Talks about *type assertions* but does not mention *assertion functions* specifically.

###### [Cheat sheet: Control Flow Analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/static/TypeScript%20Control%20Flow%20Analysis-8a549253ad8470850b77c4c5c351d457.png)

Mentions assertion functions. Does not show any way to specify a return type, but also does not explicitly say they cannot have one.

###### [v3.7 Release Notes: Assertion functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions)

Does not explicitly mention it. But does not give any examples of assertion functions that return a value. Guard functions always implicitly return a truthy or falsy (booleany?) value and it seems Assertion functions always implicitly return `void`, but it's not said outright here.

###### [Typescript Playground: Assertion functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#example/assertion-functions)

Does not demonstrate any assertion functions that return anything, but again does also not explicitly state that it's not possible...

Answer (score 2):

There is a fixed, finite set of [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values in Javascript. Some of them are not writable as literal types in Typescript, but the rest are `0`, `''`, `false`, `null` and `undefined`. You can use `Exclude` to remove them from the type parameter `T`:

```
type Truthy<T> = Exclude<T, 0 | '' | false | null | undefined>

function checkTruthy<T>(x: T): Truthy<T> {
    // ...
}
```

Or as an assertion function:

```
function assertTruthy<T>(x: T): asserts x is Truthy<T> {
    // ...
}
```

Unfortunately, as the error message in your original code says, you can't write a function type annotation that does both of these. That said, there should be no need to; if the assertion function would just return its argument unchanged, you can always refactor a call to it so that it's not in an expression:

```
// change this
let y = assertTruthy(x) + 'foo';

// to this
assertTruthy(x);
let y = x + 'foo';
```

Note that Typescript isn't able to represent types like "a non-empty string" or "a non-zero number", so e.g. `Truthy<string>` is just the same as `string` and you get no benefit regardless of whether you return or assert. So using `Exclude` on strings or numbers only really helps if you have a union of literals like `'foo' | 'bar' | ''`.

Comment: This is clever, but the refactor to a standalone variable is exactly what I was trying to avoid. If we don't want to return a value, we can also do `function assert(x: any): asserts x { ... }` and need the `Truthy` type. And the pitfalls are kind of scary for a function whose sole purpose is to ensure code correctness :)

Answer (score -2):

You can use [`NonNullable<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype):

```
function assert<T>(condition: T, msg?: string): NonNullable<T> {
  return condition ?? error(msg);
}

// workaround for https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18535
function error(msg?: string): never {
  throw new Error(msg);
}

const s: string | null = null;
const n: string = assert(s);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwM6oKYCcoB4AqAfABQQIAmMsCAXIvgDSIC2qA5gPx2pRYxhsAlHQByCESAA2k5ACNJGAoUQBvAFCJEWDFBBYkZMJWpIOHRNixwsxVkIDcagL5q1oSCYtYrNu10Q8fALCiGAYAG7YqhqIUAAWVgDuoRjJAKLe1rbsgo4uaoY8Ady8-GyIAD6hUpKIALzV0o6FUKElQeUNaJg4xKi5akA)

Comment: A check for null is not the same as a check for falsy though.

Comment: Also, this bypasses the question. Something I see a lot of developers do. There is a difference between the question and the example illustrating the question. All too often I see answers that use a workaround to address the *example*, without actually addressing the question. The question is *can assertion functions have a return value?* and pointing at `NonNullable` does not answer it. Mostly though, this behavior means the answer is just 'No'. Programmers hate to say 'No' I guess so they give workarounds instead.