# Change return type of method after call

Tags: typescript

Am I able to toggle the return type of a method? This example can probably explain it better:

```
const i = new Intersperse<number, string>();

i.next(); // number
i.next(); // string
i.next(); // number
i.next(); // string
i.next(); // number
i.next(); // string
```

I can only "toggle" but cannot return simultaneously with `asserts`:

```
class Intersperse<Item, Separator, NextIsSeparator extends boolean = false> { // Intersperse<Item, Separator>
    next(): asserts this is Intersperse<Item, Separator, NextIsSeparator extends true ? false : true> { // asserts this is Intersperse<Separator, Item>

    } 
}

const i: Intersperse<number, string> = new Intersperse();
```

But then `next` cannot return anything. Do you have any ideas? Alternatives or workarounds are of course accepted. For context, I'm *basically* copying Rust's [`std::iter::Iterator::intersperse`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.intersperse). I could type the return as `Item | Separator` but I wanted to see if there was a cheeky way to get it working at the type-level as well (although it won't be useful at all).

[Playground (`asserts` attempt)](https://tsplay.dev/Nl22BW)

Comment: Good question, but I don't know of a type checker in any language that lets the type of an object change during the flow of the program. It's something I've often thought about mocking up as a toy experiment, but I don't know of any mainstream tooling that does this.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo TypeScript is able to change the type of an object. See my linked playground and hover over `i` after each `next` call. You'll see that it toggles between `Intersperse<number, string, false>` and `Intersperse<number, string, true>`. The problem is that now I can't annotate a return type for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing [Assertion function that returns a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69435317/assertion-function-that-returns-a-value), I have come to the conclusion that this is not possible.

> An asserts return type predicate implies that the returned value is of type void, and there is no provision for returning values of other types.

This means that I can't assert (change/toggle) the type of the instance while still being able to return a value.
I can of course, still work around this by creating two separate methods, but detracts from the original point.